# When shall I use EMS and when shall I use web service (e.g. WCF)

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0, ems

I am now having an an application that publishes the changed stock positions (e.g. new, edit, cancel) using EMS; and an application that subscribes to the application using EMS and store the change into our Database. 
i am wondering whether I could use WCF to do the same thing, and what are the factors that I should consider. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot answer the question. EMS is an implementation based on the JMS standard, which again is protocol for transporting messages. WCF is a technology stack / communication framework in general from Microsoft. You can use e.g. synchronous request reply e.g. via SOAP/EMS with EMS as well as with SOAP/HTTP using WCF.

In addition with TEMS (TIBCO EMS Transport Channel) you can use WCF applying EMS transport. At the same time you can use WCF with MSMQ achieving the same using another technology stack.

You need to differentiate:

- technology stacks TIBCO vs. Microsoft
- queuing technology: EMS vs. MSMQ
- queuing (e.g. EMS, MSMQ) vs. non-queuing protocols (e.g. HTTP)

I this was somewhat helpful to clarify the problem in your question.